# Доступ к файлам по указанному пути с++

Tags: c++, файлы

Нужно записать слово "Hello" во все файлы с расширением .txt по указанному пути. (Для удобства два текстовых файла лежат в d:\ )

```
char path[10];
char mask[10] = {'*','.','t','x','t'};
cin >> path;// вводится d:\

strcat(path, mask);
_finddata_t a;
int done = _findfirst(path, &a);
ofstream in;
while(done!=-1){
    in.open(a.name);
    in << "Hello";
    in.close();
    if (_findnext(done, &a) == -1)
        break;
}
_findclose(done);
```

Собственно ничего не записывается. Хотя сами файлы находятся: делал вывод их имён в консоль - всё нормально.

Answer (score 1):

Передавая в `open` только имя файла `a.name` вместо полного пути файл будет открываться в текущей папке, которая наверняка не является диском `D` в вашем случае. Соответственно надо формировать полный путь к файлу и проверять результат открытия файла.